# filtering an observable of number[] using pipe and filter

Tags: filter, rxjs, observable

I have this really strange problem right now, which I reduced to the bare minimal code. What I want to achieve is to filter an list coming as an observable

```
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const list = of([1, 2, 3]);
return list.pipe(
  filter(x => x % 2 === 0)
);
```

I get an error that x is not number, but number[]

Of course in real life the list is loaded from a backend and the filter function is much more complicated.

rxjs 6.5.4
typescript 3.7.5

Answer (score 0):

After getting some extra coffee:

```
const list = of([1, 2, 3]);
return list.pipe(
   map(ll => ll.filter(x => x % 2 === 0))
);
```